# Did Madhwa declare the Mahabharata to be a highly corrupt text?

Tags: mahabharata, madhvacharya, madhwa

Did Madhwa declare the Mahabharata to be a highly corrupt text?

According to [this article](https://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/01-16/editorials13559.htm), he said so:

> 2. If for the sake of discussion we assume that the Kurus did attempt to disrobe Draupadi, then why did Yudhisthira remain silent? In the description of this incident found in the Mahabharata (**which Madhvacarya declared to be a highly corrupt text**) … [1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, he did. In Chapter 2 of his [Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya](https://anandatirtha.files.wordpress.com/2021/01/mbtn-eng-translation-1.pdf), he writes the following about the Mahabharata:

> 2. In the previous chapter, the decisive commentary over shastras proclaiming supremacy of the Paramatma has been made. Now the purport of the statements of the Mahabharata will be decisively brought out using the same shastra statements.
> 3. **In some places, shlokas have been inserted; In other places, shlokas that go against one's philosophy have been removed; In some places, shlokas have been re-arranged; Along with this, due to wrong knowledge and illusion, the contents of the work have been distorted.**
> 4. Those works which are currently extant also have such distortions; Amongst works, those
>    which are now not available are more in number. Even one percent of the works among a crore are not available nowadays,